# The metric of "the measure of the symmetric difference" and the Hausdorff distance

Tags: geometry, analysis, measure-theory, symmetry, hausdorff-distance

For a given measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \mu)$ **the symmetric difference semimetric** $d_{\Delta}$ is a semimetric on the set $\mathcal A_{\mu}=\{A \in \mathcal A: \;\mu(A) <\infty \}$ defined by: $d_{\Delta}(A,B)=\mu(A\Delta B)$ where $A \Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B \setminus A)$.

> ***QUESTION:*** Can we find an upper bound for $d_{\Delta}$ in terms of the Hausdorff metric $d_{H}$? Is there any constant $C>0$ such that
>   $d_{\Delta}(A,B) \le C \delta_{H}(A,B)$?

So far, the above question seemed valid to me (although I am not extremely familiar with these metrics). However, I read in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Hausdorff_distance_vs._symmetric_difference) that "When the Hausdorff distance becomes smaller, the area of the symmetric difference between them becomes larger" so I started to have doubts.

I would appreciate if someone could verify/reject this question and provide some short explanation on the differences between these two metrics.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That sentence "When the Hausdorff distance becomes smaller, the area of the symmetric difference between them becomes larger" isn't supposed to refer to sets in general; it's talking about a specific sequence of sets (in particular, a sequence of sets showing that that bound does not exist)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich so this yields that some additional assumptions must be imposed on the sets in order for such bound to exist probably?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, such an inequality is not possible. Let $A_n:=[0,n]\times[0,1]$ and $B_n:=[0,n]\times[0,1+\delta]$. Then the Hausdorff distance is $\delta$, but $d_\Delta(A_n,B_n)=\mu(A_n\triangle B_n)=n\delta$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. I suppose is what I read in wiki. If instead of these sets , we had some level sets of continuous functions, would the inequality be trivially invalid as well?

Comment: Yes most likely, because the Hausdorff metric is based on a distance (eg between the level sets) while the symmetric difference measure scales like an area, say, so as the level sets get longer, the area (or higher measure) increases indefinitely.